# Нужна помощь в написании драйвера на C++

Tags: c++, драйвер

Обшарив очень много форумов/сайтов не смог найти ничего полезного по поводу написания драйвера на C++.
Хочу написать простой драйвер, который будет давать о себе знать при включении и выключении компьютера.
Что делать?

Comment: Как бы это выразиться... Для каждой операционки правила игры свои, и одним только C++ вряд ли удастся обойтись.

Comment: Что-то мне не ясно что вы конкретно хотите.

Comment: @Harry он хочет типо логи делать включения выключения? Я не догоняю

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко Да для начала, как я понимаю, такой, который просто будет как-то о себе сообщать. Пищать, например :)

Comment: C++ требует библиотек поддержки. А драйвера в большинстве ОС не могут использовать стандартные библиотеки. И пишутся они по этой причине на чистом C

Comment: @Mike, не совсем чистом С, там 1. можно добавить заголовки интерпритирующие С++ (не всегда) 2. чистым С это назвать нельзя - очень специфический диалект.

Comment: @Mike с чего это не могут использовать стандартные библиотеки, ещё как могут

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, могут, но ключевое слово тут - "уровень прерывания"

Comment: @Mirdin А чего там может быть специфического ? Чистый C включает в себя только операторы и управляющие конструкции, все остальное, включая базовые функции на подобии pritntf() - это уже не язык, а именно функции стандартной библиотеки. В ядре все свое.

Comment: @Mirdin ключевое слово тут "гладиолус" (и статическая линковка)

Comment: @Mike, я о том что а, язык DDK не соответствует каким либо стандартам (конечно сейчас это могло и изменится, я не интересовался данной сферой уже лет 10), он просто "свой", б, далеко не всегда можно вызывать одни функции из других, приходится учитывать их уровни. (Что для новичка может послужить неприятным сюрпризом)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, три варианта вашего "гладиолуса": 1. вы троллите 2. вы говорите о такой специфической теме, как драйверы пользовательского режима, 3. вы говорите вообще о чем то левом.

Comment: @Mirdin Похоже вы просто не в теме, тогда лучше не комментируйте. У меня за плечами не один драйвер с использованием C++ и различных библиотек (и не только стандартных).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, ОК, если вы профессионал, устыдите, нас дилетантов, своим развернутым профессиональным ответом, как писать драйверы, а не мелкими ехидными комментами.

Comment: @Mirdin Составляйте и дальше ваши списки, не собираюсь вступать с вами в дискуссию. (в принципе не вступаю в дискуссию с мелкими и ехидными пользователями).

Answer (score 7):

Для начала вам нужно основательно проштудировать Руссиновича. Потом Уолтера Они. Потом сделать песочницу, в которой будете запускать свой драйвер (WinDBG + VirtualKD + VM Ware + ОС), очень неприятно переставлять виндовс каждые полчаса. Потом выкачиваете DDK и символы. Потом все это долго настраиваете, связывая студию, VM Ware, DDK compiler, символы -- мануалы в сети есть, но от танцев с бубном вас это не избавит. Если к этому моменту вам не опротивеет сама мысль о драйверах, то вы обнаружите что DDK не работает с классическими С и С++, там что то весьма специфическое, учитывающее кстати уровни прерывания и "прочие кишки системы", напоминающее больше всего древний K&R. Если, и это, вас не напугает, можете приступать к экспериментам.

Comment: Вы уверены, что ТС надо драйвер под винду?

Comment: @alexolut не уверен :), но 1.мануалы 2.песочница 3.DDK 4. "танцы с бубном" будут скорее всего везде, только названия будут разные. Уровни прерывания например зависят не от ОС, а от процессора, поэтому отдельный режим ядра и пользователя будет у любой ОС на Intel платформе.

Comment: @Mirdin И пожалуйста не называйте уровни привилегий, уровнями прерываний. это разные понятия

Comment: @Mike, sorry, я об этой теме уже много забыл :).